# Computing $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ of sheaves over elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $p \in C$ be any point. I am trying to prove that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_C(p), \mathcal{O}_C) \simeq k$.

I tried to consider some exact sequences of sheaves relating these two (such as $0 \rightarrow I_p \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C(p) \rightarrow 0$, where $I_p$ is the ideal sheaf of the point $p$) and to use some homological dualities/Riemann-Roch theorems, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: If $E,F$ are vectorbundles on a variety $X$, $\operatorname{Ext}^n(E,F)=H^n(E^*\otimes F)$, where $E^*$ is the dual. So, in your case, you want $H^1(O(p))$, which is zero, not $k$ as you want.

Comment: Thank you! This actually was a typo, and I corrected it now. But this formula also solves the corrected problem, since $\text{Ext}^1(O(p), O) = H^1(O(-p)) = k$, right?